# Does amdgpu support my Fury X and why isn't the driver loaded?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, graphics, amd-graphics

Currently my linux machine only can detect one monitor and seems to be running the bare minimum for graphic support. My system seems to recognize that the card is a Fury X but doesn't load any drivers for it. Mesa knows how to use the card anyways (which is strange) but it only can display on my first monitor.

Can/should I alias the card to use AMDGPU or does it not yet support the fury x? If so, how would I go about doing the modalias?

**[glxinfo](http://pastebin.com/SRSbra0r)**

**lspci**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Fiji [Radeon R9 FURY Series] (rev c8) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Radeon R9 FURY X
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at fea40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [200] #15
        Capabilities: [270] #19
        Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [2c0] #13
        Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
        Capabilities: [328] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
```

**lshw**

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Fiji [Radeon R9 FURY Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: c8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:fea40000-fea5ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around on forums and in the kernel I discovered that Fiji isn't supported yet. Partial support is expected in 4.3 and full support in 4.4.

Comment: Testing confirmed that my gpu worked in 4.3 although the X server crashes when using amdgpu.